# Can you make a class attribute a specific instance of that class within the class definition?

Tags: python, class-attributes

Was wondering if there was a way to set a class attribute to a specific instance from within the class definition. For example,

```
class Value:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    # Something like
    # half = Value(0.5)

>>> Value.half.x
0.5
>>> Value.half.half.x
0.5
```

I'm also aware I can easily set it outside the class that seems a bit more bulky and error prone, like this

```
class Value:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

Value.half = Value(0.5)

>>> Value.half.x
0.5
>>> Value.half.half.x
0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

No. At the time the body of the class is being evaluated, the class doesn't yet exist. A class statement is a declarative syntax for calling a metaclass:

```
class Value:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
def init(self, x):
    self.x = x


Value = type('Value', (object,), {'__init__': init})
```

Your class attribute would have to be a member of the `dict` passed as the third argument, which has to be fully defined before `type` is called.

Answer (score 0):

not quite, but you can make a class method that return a new instance of your class in whatever way you want with the [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator

```
>>> class Value:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x=x

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{type(self).__name__}({self.x})"

    @classmethod
    def half(cls):
        return cls(0.5)

    
>>> Value(10)
Value(10)
>>> Value.half()
Value(0.5)
>>>
```

look like in py3.9 you can combine it with the property decorator to accomplish just that, see linked documentation above (but I don't have it at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can't because the class hasn't yet existed. But you can use either metaclass or class decorator to achieve the same goal as the following shows:

```
#Metaclass
class Meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, clsname, clsbases, clsdict):
        cls.half = cls(0.5)

class Value(metaclass=Meta):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

#Decorator
def decorator(cls):
    cls.half = cls(0.5)
    return cls

@decorator
class Value2:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

print(Value.half.half.x)
print(Value.half.x)
print(Value2.half.half.x)
print(Value2.half.x)
```